# loop adds only the last element to the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is only the last item shown instead of all? The history2 table only shows me the last element and the condition contains more elements

```
state = {
history2:[]
}

 for (const point of this.state.idRt) {
      if (id === point.RouteId) {
        this.setState({
          history2: {
            Name: point.Name,
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append to the state object that you have instead of replacing it. Something like this,

```
state = {
  history2: [],
};

for (const point of this.state.idRt) {
  if (id === point.RouteId) {
    this.setState({
      history2: [
        ...this.state.history2,
        {
          Name: point.Name,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```